# Install Notepad++ as remote app on windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I'm trying to install Notepad++ as a rempote app for a windows 2012 based rdp.

I've rdp up and running with the 3 preinstalled apps calculater, wordpad and paint. Now I want to add some more apps.

I went to the remote programs list and opened the task pop-up to publish a romte app. Notepad++ showed up in the list and I just marked it and pressed the ok button.

Now Notepad++ shows up if a user logs in (whithout icon), but starting it reuslts in a 404 message.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldnt be surprised if its caused by the "++" in the name. Try and rename the app?

Comment: Removing the ++ in the path and the exe file name solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: lucky guess :-)